# How to use tensorflow2.0 dataset with keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

i am using tensorflow 2.0 API where i created a dataset from all image paths like example below

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_image_paths, all_image_labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=32)

path_train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_train)
image_train_ds = path_train_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

However, i am getting error when i ran this code to apply some agumentation using  keras ImageDataGenerator

```
datagen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True,
        featurewise_std_normalization=True,
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
datagen.fit(image_train_ds)
```

**Error:**

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py in fit(self, x, augment, rounds, seed)
    907             seed: Int (default: None). Random seed.
    908        """
--> 909         x = np.asarray(x, dtype=self.dtype)
    910         if x.ndim != 4:
    911             raise ValueError('Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. '

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
    503 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ParallelMapDataset'
```

Answer (score 5):

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` does not work with a `tf.data.Dataset` object, it has been designed to work with plain old images.

If you want to apply augmentation you have to use the `tf.data.Dataset` object itself (via various `.map` call) or you can create a `tf.data.Dataset` object after having created an augmented dataset using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`.

Comment: If true, this is an unbelievably stupid design choice.